# scanf doesn't take input in debug mode in eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

First of all there is another question with the same title but the solutions offered there didn't work for me. [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126703/scanf-doesnt-appear-to-work-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse-cdt-with-gdb/31299426)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    fflush(stdout);//suggested solution in other question
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("Values entered: %d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine when I run it normally.

**Output**

```
1 2 3
Values entered: 1 2 3
```

But when I run in debug mode nothing is printed. When I hover over the variables they have these values.

a : 56

b : 6422420

c : 6422420

Another solution suggested was to put this code in the start of the main method.

```
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); //suggested solution #1
```

Both solutions suggested in the post didn't work for me. I tried them both separately.

EDIT

OS : Windows 10

Compiler : MinGW

Comment: What compiler (Eclipse is *not* a compiler) and what operating system you are using?

Comment: I recommend compiling on the command line. Eclipse is just hiding things to you.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, don't specify both when asking about your program.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use spaces in your `scanf` format, and to test its return count, so:

```
a = b = c = 0; // better to clear variables, helpful for debugging at least
int cnt = 0;
if ((cnt=scanf(" %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)) == 3) {
  /// successful input
  printf("Values entered: %d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}
else { 
  /// failed input
  printf("scanf failure cnt=%d error %s\n", cnt, strerror(errno));
}
fflush(NULL); // probably not needed, at least when stdout is a terminal
```

Read *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and of every library function) before using it.

BTW, Eclipse is just an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), your compiler could be [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (and you probably can configure your IDE to pass appropriate options to your compiler). And `scanf` itself is implemented in your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (above your operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))).

But you really need to enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler (so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and to learn how to use your [debugger `gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (breakpoints, step by step, variable querying, backtrace...)

You may want to use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) and you should compile and run your program in a terminal (not under Eclipse, which is hiding a lot of useful things to you).

Comment: I tried your code.
It skips to the   `perror("scanf failure");` part without entering the if condition.
Note : works find normally. This only happens in debug mode.

Comment: But did you read carefully the documentation of `scanf` ? BTW, I slightly improved my code.